I want to loop through column and add filtered df into template with same format, delete extra rows from the workbook
I have dataframe and want to loop through city column, filter city wise data and add in master file which is template and save file with city name. Master file contains same number column as template df, with formatting, and has 3 sheets.
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'State': ['Colorado', 'Colorado', 'Colorado', 'Colorado'], 
    'County': ['Denver', 'El Paso', 'Larimar', 'Larimar'],
    'City': ['Denver', 'Colorado Springs', 'Fort Collins', 'Loveland']
})
for city_name in df['City'].unique():
    df_city=df[df['City']==city_name]
    for val in df_city['Country'].unique():
        accountname=val
        template=pd.DataFrame(columns=['State','Country','City','Pincode','Corporater','Population'])
        template['State']=df_city['State']
        template['Country']=df_city['Country']
        template['City']=df_city['City']
        template['Pincode']=''
        template['Corporater']='Mr.'
        template['Population']=''
        template=template.reset_index()
       #load Master file with some fix formatting and columns want to ad data from template into Master file and save file
        workbook=load_workbook('Master.xlsm',keep_vba=True)
        sheet=workbook['Ind']
        title1=f"{vote_startdate.strftime('%d%d%y')}"
        last_row=last_row+1
        for index,row in template.iterrows():
            for col,value in enumerate(row,start=2):
                sheet.cell(rows=last_row+index,column=col,value=value)
                sheet.cell(row=2,column=2,value=accountname)
        for row in range(sheet.max_row,0,-1):
            if sheet.cell(row=row,column=6).value is not None:
                last_row=row
                break
        last_row=last_row+1
        if last_row<113:
            num_rows_to_delete=113-last_row
            sheet.delete_rows(last_row,num_rows_to_delete)

        sheet=workbook['Rule']
        sheet.cell(row=3,column=2,value=vote_startdate.strftime("%b%y")
        sheet=workbook['Front Page']
        sheet.cell(row=5,column=2,value=accountname)
        output=(f'{city_name[0]}_{accountname}}.xlsm')
        workbook.save(output)

With this code i am able to filter data as but no able to add in workbook. It works only for 1st city value. It saves accurate workbook, but for further city value it saves master file as it is without adding data.

It looks like the initial part of your code, in which you define the df, is incomplete. Please edit your post so that it is reproducible.

As @Luca mentioned, you can share some examples about your input, and expected output so we can test
